# Asp.Net Google style file upload

Tags: asp.net

Does someone knows of a user control that can work exactly like the file upload Google has?
I want that the use will select the files to upload, then that upload will start and the progress bar will work, and the user can continue to the next field he has to fill in the page as the file is uploaded in the background.

Willing to pay. Free is better.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently used [AjaxUploader](http://ajaxuploader.com/) with great results. One of its demos is actually [GMail Style](http://ajaxuploader.com/demo/multiple-files-upload.aspx). It runs $99 for 1 domain.